# How can i delete a cookie on server side?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, session-cookies

I am using Node.js without hosting it on server to get the user name from a third party platform. I am setting that cookie as `res.cookie("username",req.session.user)`. I have deleted the cookie on client side and i cannot find that in any of the web storages/cookies. However i can cookie in Response-Headers. Is there any way I delete/hide them on client side, since I am a front end engineer and I want to control it on client side.

Here is the Response-Headers:

```
Set-Cookie: userName=User; Path=/ Set-Cookie: userName=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how cookies work, they aren't stored on your server ever. Their content might (session ID) but your server holds no information of any cookie sent/set.

See how cookies are set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

You can unset them in the client by setting the expire time to a past date.